Dependent Types in $\lambda P$ vs MLTT
I am trying to understand the difference between $\lambda P$ and MLT, in particular the dependent type features.
What is the difference between dependent types in $\lambda P$ and dependent types in MLTT?
It appears that in $\lambda P$ you can have type constructors. For example, the following is derivable in $\lambda P$,
$$ A:\ast, P:(A\rightarrow \ast),a:A\vdash P(a):\ast,$$
and I think even abstract over $a$ to get a type constructor term for $P(a)$, something like $\lambda a:A.P(a)$, but I do not see how to do this in MLTT (for example, as presented in Rijke's book). In MLTT, how do I make the judgment that $P(a) \ \mathrm{Type} $ if I know that $\Pi_{a:A}P(a)\ \mathrm{Type}$ and $a:A$?
